# c# mySQL count results

Tags: c#, mysql, count, rows

I have this code here and I want to count how many rows it returns:

```
    public void connectToDB()
        {
            DBConnect connection = new DBConnect();
            MySqlDataAdapter adapter;
            DataSet DS;

            if (connection.Connect())
            {
                StatusTextLabel.Text = "Connected";
            } 
            else
                StatusTextLabel.Text = "Error Connecting to DB!";


            //SHOW THE CARS TABLE  
            adapter = new MySqlDataAdapter("SELECT cars.carID, cars.carBrand, cars.carModel, cars.fuelType, cars.airbags, cars.topSpeed, cars.abs, " +
                "cars.esp, cars.color, cars.cost, cars.humanResourcesNeeded, cars.metalNeeded, cars.rubberNeeded, cars.electronicsNeeded FROM `cars` ", 
                connection.connection);            
            DS = new DataSet();            
            adapter.Fill(DS);                       
            carTable.DataSource = DS.Tables[0];
            carTable.Columns[0].HeaderText = "Car ID";
            carTable.Columns[1].HeaderText = "Brand";
            carTable.Columns[2].HeaderText = "Model";
            carTable.Columns[3].HeaderText = "Fuel Type";
            carTable.Columns[4].HeaderText = "Airbags";
            carTable.Columns[5].HeaderText = "Top Speed";
            carTable.Columns[6].HeaderText = "ABS";
            carTable.Columns[7].HeaderText = "ESP";
            carTable.Columns[8].HeaderText = "Color";
            carTable.Columns[9].HeaderText = "Price";
            carTable.Columns[10].HeaderText = "Human Resources Needed";
            carTable.Columns[11].HeaderText = "Metal Needed";
            carTable.Columns[12].HeaderText = "Rubber Needed";
            carTable.Columns[13].HeaderText = "Electronics Needed";
}
```

I cant find anything that works with adapter. Everyone talks about SQLCommand. Can it be done using my way?

Comment: Sure. DataSets have Datatables, and they contain rows: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms135388(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: try this `DS.Tables[0].Rows.Count`

Comment: Thank you both! That did the trick!

Answer (score 0):

DataSets have Datatables, and they contain rows: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms135388(v=vs.110).aspx

try `DS.Tables[0].Rows.Count`